# JSLint - Bad Escaping for a Regex with variables

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext2, jslint

I've seen some posts about **JSLint "bad escapement"** warnings, but I just wanted to see if I'm doing this Regex correctly.  (Note - I'm dabbler programmer).

I have a function (below) that attempts to parse out a variable from it's name in a long message.  The regex is working well, but ***should I change something in response to the JSLint warning?***

A very simplified version of msg could look like this essentially:

> *VariableName1 = Value1 
>
>   VariableName2 = Value2 
>
>   VariableName3 = Value3*

The actual msg has different unstructured data above and below.  I had to use a strange Regex since even though a more simple one worked on all the testing websites, it didn't work within the server application we are using, so this is the only way I could get it to work.  The regular expression incorporates a variable.

Here is the parsing function I'm using:

```
    function parseValue(msg, strValueName) {
        var myRegexp = new RegExp(strValueName + ' = ([A-Z3][a-zA-Z\. 3]+)[\\n\\r]+', 'gm');
        log('parseValue', 'myRegexp = ' + myRegexp.toString());
        var match = myRegexp.exec(msg);
        log('parseValue', 'returning match = ' + match[1] );
        return match[1];
    }
```

There is probably something much simpler that a 'real' programmer can come up with pretty easily.  Any help would be appreciated.

THanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `bad escapements`, but you don't need `\.`, just `.` will do inside of a character class.  Maybe you can try that.

Comment: I am not sure about the warning. However, do note that `strValueName` may contain character that has special meaning in regex, which will mess up the resulting regex.

Comment: Good point on the variable potentially having regex characters.  I was using it in a controlled implementation and a single project but I should probably make it more robust by escaping all special characters.

Comment: I'll try removing the escape character from the character class also.  THanks.

Comment: Explosion Pills - Yes, that was the problem that JSLint was warning me about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that JSLint didn't like was the '.' character in the character class as pointed out by 'Explosion Pills'.

When I removed the '.' all was good.

Thanks.